# Как сделать элемент в середине на всю оставшуюся ширину?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть три элемента, крайние имеют ширину по контенту внутри ( текст ) , нужно, чтобы средний элемент растягивался на всю ширину, которая остается, т.е. был резиновым.
Я знаю, как сделать на флексах, НО этот вариант не работает в IE 10!!!!
Я знаю, что надо задать им ширину каждому и тогда более менее будет работать, но можно ли именно, чтоб крайние по контенту, а в середине на остаток?
Спасибо

Comment: так флекс или не флекс?

Comment: не важно как, главное чтобы работало в IE 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если, ставите минус, аргументируйте

Comment: Правильный пример, раньше так и верстали. Выровнял.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div{
 width: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
}
div.center{
 width: calc(100% - 200px);
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div class="center">2</div><div>3</div>
```